# Error in the lib version of android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I'm trying to build my Android Project but when I rebuild I receive this error message:

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>     - butterknife-5.1.2.jar (butterknife-5.1.2.jar)
>
> Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>   See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wakeup.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 28
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```

}

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Explict Annotation Processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993587/setting-explict-annotation-processor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, edit build.gradle file:

[image: error]